# Problema con Metodos y Argumentos JAVA

Tags: java, método

Tengo un método **x** que recibe un parametro entero, y tengo un método **z** el cual para poder funcionar utiliza el método **x**.

Mi problema es que me requieren que no utilice variables globales.
Por lo tanto no puedo preguntar el parámetro del método **x** y guardarlo en una variable para posteriormente utilizarla en el método **z**

¿Alguien sabría alguna forma para poder hacerlo como me lo requieren?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por variable global se entiende te refieres a una de tipo **static**.

En lugar de eso, puedes ocupar un atributo de clase en el cual asignes el valor del parámetro del método **X**, y posteriormente recuperarlo en el método **Z**.

```
private int x;

private void metodoZ(){
    metodoX(10);
    System.out.println(this.x); // Imprimirá 10 en consola
}

private void metodoX(int parametro){
    this.x = parametro;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ret contendra el multiplo de 10;

```
int ret = metodoZ(10);

public int metodoZ(int param){
    int u;
    u = metodoX(param);

    return u
}

public int metodoX(int parametro){
    int i;
    i = parametro * 10;

    return i;
}
```